# "My English is good" is this grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is "My English is good" grammatically correct? My friend says it is grammatically incorrect. Correct form would be "I am good at English."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct and means "my command of English is good". The version your friend suggested is correct too.